# Use Cookies to prevent user clicking link twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, cookies

I am trying to prevent the class .activeAdv being added if the link within has it's URL stored in cookie, this cooke is added if user clicks links so basically I am trying to stop returning users clicking same link twice.

The link is by default hidden underneath a div which animates on addition of .activeAdv class, revealing link.

Current code is below along with codepen example of project. I'm guessing I need to wrap the activeAdv addClass in an IF conditional which:

- Gets value of child link's href
- Check to see if a matching cookie exists
- Only add .activeAdv if condition returns false

I think I have the right idea and have got as far as setting cookie on click of link, I am struggling with the IF statement though, could anyone lend a hand?

http://codepen.io/Jambob/pen/wKyoRr

```
        <article>
             <div id="on-1" class="box">
                 <h2>1 dec</h2>
             </div>
             <div class="present">
                content
               <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
             </div>
         </article>


    // Checks for content within .present, if TRUE adds .activeAdv animation class
    $(".present").filter(function(){
        return $(this).html().trim().length > 0;
    }).parent().addClass('activeAdv');


    // When link clicked, store its URL in cookie
    $( ".present a" ).click(function() {
       $.cookie($(this).attr('href'), true);
    });

    if ( '(".present").html().trim().length > 0;' ) {
        if ( '(".present a").attr("href")' === "http://www.google.com") {
            $(this).parent().addClass('activeAdv');
        }
    }
```

After a bit of thinking I have come up with a different IF statement which may be along the right lines

```
    // Checks if content exists
    if ( '(".present").html().trim().length > 0;' ) {

        // Checks if HREF of child link matches existing cookie (using a string for testing)
        if ( '(".present a").attr("href")' === "http://www.google.com") {
            $(this).parent().addClass('activeAdv');
        }
    }
```

Comment: What the hell is this: `'(".present").html().trim().length > 0;'`? Also are you sure you need a cookie? [Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is [safe to use now](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) and doesn't increase your server bandwidth.

Comment: Finally, are you aware of `:visited` pseudoclass?

Comment: @TomášZato that code simply checks if .present contains any html content

Comment: It is commented so I guess rather than asking what the code does you are suggesting is it poorly written..

Comment: No, I wasn't suggesting anything about your code. If you want to *"comment"* your `if`, use this: `if(true || ... original statement)`. The only think I am suggesting is that you don't use cookies - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So if `:visited` CSS pseudoclass isn't sufficient (it matches visited links), you can make use of `localStorage`, which is much more dedicated to this purpose. I created script which can be run out the Firebug console and colors non-visited links:

```
(function(links) {
  // Load visited links from local storage
  var visited = JSON.parse(localStorage["visited"]||"[]");
  // Safety check
  if(!visited instanceof Array) {
      visited = []; 
      localStorage["visited"] = [];
  }

  function setClassToLinks() {
    links.each(function(){
      // Remember state - asume not visited
      var linkVisited = false;


      // Check for inner HTML
      if(this.innerHTML.trim().length > 0) {
          // Check if in list of visited links
          if(visited.indexOf(this.href)==-1)
            linkVisited = true;
          else
            console.log("Already visited: "+this.href);
      }
      else
          // Skip empty links
          return console.log("No inner HTML.");
      // Reset color
      this.style.color = !linkVisited?"":"red";
      // And remove class 
      if(linkVisited)
          $(this).removeClass("activeAdv");
      else
          $(this).addClass("activeAdv");
    })
  }
  setClassToLinks();
  // When link clicked, store its URL in LocalStorage
  links.click(function() {
     // Prevent duplicities
     if(visited.indexOf(this.href)==-1) {
         visited.push(this.href);
         localStorage["visited"] = JSON.stringify(visited);
     }
  });
  // [OPTIONAL] Update links realtime - triggers when local storage changes
  window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {
      if(event.key=="visited") {
          visited = JSON.parse(localStorage["visited"]||"[]");
          // Change CSS
          setClassToLinks();
      }
  });

})($("a"));
```

Neat aspect of my solution is, that the links automatically update when you browse in different tab (provided this tab has run the script).

The `visited` array may quickly grow, which is why I think cookie is such a bad idea.

Comment: I like this, the reason for using Cookies was that I couldn't think of an alternative except for using a login / registration. 

There will be a total of 25 links (project is for a Christmas Advent Calendar)

Comment: I have added this script to my page and it is logging visited links in console, how would I prevent addClass from running if child link has already been visited?

Comment: This is not paste and use code. You will probably want to remove consol log (I left it there so you can debug it, if you need). And you're going to have to re-add the child parent pattern, I didn't stick to that. I did the part you asked about, not the part you already know.

Comment: Thats cool, not a big fan of copy and paste code I much prefer to understand what I'm using, otherwise you never learn...

Problem is, I do not have much experience using local storage so having difficulty implementing your solution.

On a side note, nice Warhammer avatar ;)

Comment: I implemented all the local storage stuff. All you do is that you expect list of visited links in `visited` array. To check if something is in array, use `.indexOf`, like I did. If you wanna do something with links parent nodes, use `this.parentNode` in the `.each` loop callback

Comment: If you have any specific question, tell me in chat, not here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93170/tmp-0666